# Flash timeline stops when setting mc x coordinate

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Simple Question (perhaps?)

I have a movie clip on frame 1 with instance name "mc".
On frame 10 I set the alpha to 0 and create a classic tween.

Everything works fine. movie clip fades out and stops att frame 10.

I then add a small action script on frame 5:
mc.x = 500;

Now, the fade works as before but when it reaches frame 5 it moves the mc to x coordinate 500 and then stops. Why does it stop?

I want to be able to move the mc do a desired x coordinate but then i want everything to continue running...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's the common issue with the timeline tweens - you can't modify properties of animated instances, it will broke the animation. But there is a simple solution - wrap you `mc` with another movie clip - animate wrapper, but change coordinate of the internal `mc`.